# rumps.notification not working - silently fails to show notification

Tags: python-3.x, macos, rumps

I have a simple python3.9 rumps app, roughly following the documented example https://rumps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html.

main.py:

```py
import rumps


class SiMenuBarApp(rumps.App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SiMenuBarApp, self).__init__("SiProdHacks")
        self.menu = ["Item1"]

    @rumps.clicked("Item1")
    def item_one(self, _):
        print("Hi Si!")
        rumps.notification("SiProdHacks", "Keeping Si's Brain Free since 2021", "KAPOWIE!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = SiMenuBarApp()
    app.icon = "happyicon.png"
    app.run()
```

It runs fine, but when I click the menu bar item1, it prints my console message, but no notification occurs.

I am using `python 3.9.0`, `rumps=0.3.0`, `iTerm` and `Mac OS 10.15.7` (Catalina).

Console output is:

```sh
❯ pipenv run python main.py
Hi Si!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I did some more digging on this, and discovered the debug mode of rumps:

```py
import rumps
rumps.debug_mode(True)
```

which added the following to the output:

```sh
In this case there is no file at "/Users/simonrowland/.local/share/virtualenvs/si-menu-productivity-mlyLc7OG/bin/Info.plist"

Running the following command should fix the issue:
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :CFBundleIdentifier string "rumps"' /Users/simonrowland/.local/share/virtualenvs/si-menu-productivity-mlyLc7OG/bin/Info.plist
```

Running the suggested command:

```sh
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :CFBundleIdentifier string "rumps"' ${PATH_TO_VENV_BIN_DIR}/bin/Info.plist
```

Made it work!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For other's stumbling on this. It may be that you don't have notifications enabled for pylauncher while running your menu bar app in the IDE.